# How to create postgresql query in golang for filter

Tags: postgresql

When I write filter I want to give parameters with $

My query is in this situation

```
q:= `select m.*, ms.fullname as singer, l.name as lang, c.name as country  
     from music m
    LEFT JOIN music_singer ms ON ms.uuid = m.singer_id
    LEFT JOIN language l ON l.uuid = m.language_id
    LEFT JOIN countries c ON c.uuid = m.country_id 
        where m.status = true `
if dto.LanguageID != "" {
    q += ` and ( m.language_id='` + dto.LanguageID + `' ) `
}

if dto.CountryID != "" {
    q += ` and ( m.country_id='` + dto.CountryID + `' ) `
}

rows, err := r.client.Query(ctx, q)
defer rows.Close()
...
```

I want to write my query like this

```
limit:= 20
page:= 0

q:= `select * from feed limit $1 offset $2`
rows, err := r.client.Query(ctx, q, limit, page)
defer rows.Close()
```

I want to give parameter like "LanguageID" and "CountryID"   "limit" and "page"

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Generating our own dynamic query based on the conditions are good approach, but it will take more time to design and test to ensure that it works correclty and efficiently.
And it will be bit harden for complex queries.

**You need to be careful about sql injection if you generate the query dynamically by concatenating strings**

Instead of checking the condition and preparing the query by using the concatenation approach, you can use  [Squirrel](https://github.com/Masterminds/squirrel) query builder package which will helps you to build SQL queries.

```
import sq "github.com/Masterminds/squirrel"

func main() {
    queryBuilder := sq.StatementBuilder.PlaceholderFormat(sq.Dollar)

    selectQuery := queryBuilder.Select("*").From("table t")
    
    if dto.LanguageID != "" {
        selectQuery = selectQuery.Where(sq.Eq{
            "t.language_id": dto.LanguageID,
        })
    }

    if dto.CountryID != "" {
        selectQuery = selectQuery.Where(sq.Eq{
            "t.country_id": dto.LanguageID,
        })
    }

    selectQuery = selectQuery.Limit(10).Offset(2)

    sql, args, err := selectQuery.ToSql()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    rows, err := r.client.Query(ctx, sql, args...)
    defer rows.Close()
}
```